# Expo EAS Error while building at Run Gradlew step

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas

I'm learning React-Native for a project.
My react-native project is under Expo, as this option lets you build and test your application faster. Expo allows you to do away with certain configurations, such as Android or iOS (that's what I understand).

After creating

- a Expo account
- Fixing dependencies
- Building a expo android prebuild

I am still unable to finish a build for my little project.

It seems to fail everytime at the `Run Gradlew` step.

---

The log is more than 400 lines so I'm posting only the error ([stderr]) :

```html
Error: @build-script-error-begin
Error loading assets JSON from Metro. Ensure you've followed all expo-updates installation steps correctly. App.js: /home/expo/workingdir/build/App.js: Use process(css).then(cb) to work with async plugins
@build-script-error-end
    at /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-updates/scripts/createManifest.js:59:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.

-----------

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:createReleaseExpoManifest'.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.

-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 3m 17s
98 actionable tasks: 98 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

I have tried to update everything here and there to fix warning and potential errors.

This is my dependencies versions if it can help :

```html
"expo": "~48.0.18",
"expo-font": "~11.1.1",
"expo-location": "~15.1.1",
"expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
"expo-task-manager": "~11.1.1",
"expo-updates": "~0.16.4",
    
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.8",
```

Don't hesitate to ask more about my configuration or information.
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: What was the fix for you?

Comment: @MarioMurrent I think I started a new project without the EAS system in EXPO. Don't know why but it was crashing every build with EAS.

Comment: A I see - yeah I fixed it with deleting the yarn.lock file. Definitely no idea why this helped :D